# I can get entity by ID after getting entity by username only. Is it a bug? Video from shell

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I can get entity by ID after getting entity by username only. Is it a bug? Video from shell

I'm using Mac and python 3

I'm trying to get entity by id

`entity = client.get_entity(1151511560)`

but get an exception:

```
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for <telethon.tl.types.PeerUser object at 0x1172312e8>. Please read https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/entities.html to find out more details.
```

Then I'm successfully getting an entity by username "ekat01"

After that i successfully get an entity by id.

Why I can't get an entity by id only? I think, it's a bug, isn't it?

Video with proofs by the link: https://youtu.be/mnDNZZir5PY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github -------------------------------------------------

From **juanvelascogomez**:

If I am not wrong, that is explained in the docs "Users, chat and channel, Important section": https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/entities.html

Once the library has “seen” the entity, you can use their integer ID. You can’t use entities from IDs the library hasn’t seen. You must make the library see them at least once and disconnect properly. You know where the entities are and you must tell the library. It won’t guess for you.

From **Lonami**:

On a clean session,

```
with client:
    try:
        client.get_entity(1151511560)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error as expected')

    client.get_entity("ekat01")
    client.get_entity(1151511560)
    print('Works as expected')
prints:
```

Error as expected
Works as expected
On a second run,

```
with client:
    client.get_entity(1151511560)
    print('Works as expected')
prints:
```

Works as expected